# Regex named capture group does not work

Tags: regex, capture-group

I'm having the weirdest problem, and I know it must be something trivial I'm overlooking. I'm writing a simple regular expression which works fine, until I try and name my capture group. For an example, you can reproduce this on http://www.regexr.com/.

Text to match:

```
'1.2.3.4'
```

Regex to use:

```
'(.*?)'
```

This works fine and it matches the version number. But when I change the regex to:

```
'(?<VersionNumber>.*?)'
```

it no longer matches and regexr says `Error: Invalid quantifier for target` on the first question mark. I've also confirmed the same results in my C# app. What am I doing wrong here?

This is a pretty simple example, so I'm not sure what is incorrect. I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906974/named-capture-group-in-regex), which describes a similar problem, but the answer just provides the OP with the new regex to use, instead of actually telling him why his original regex was not valid.

---

UPDATE

Answer was that regexr.com no longer supports named capture groups, and I must have goofed up my regex in C# the first time around, as it worked fine when I rewrote it.

Comment: [Why make it lazy, use `(?<VersionNumber>.*)`](http://regex101.com/r/xD7sU2/1)

Comment: I want it to be lazy to cover my bases in case the text to match is ever changed to something like "'1.2.3.4' '5.6.7.8'". Basically it's future proofing. And this is actually just a skimmed down simple example that demonstrates the problem; not the regex I will actually be using in my final app. I tried removing the lazy ? anyways, but it still has the same problem.

Comment: Did you see my linked demo where it is working fine. For making it non-greedy you need to have something after `.*?`

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/ claims to use the javascript flavor of regex, which doesn't support named capture groups at all, so it's never going to work there

Comment: Thanks @anubhava and roel-harbers. I retested my regex in C# again and it did in fact work this time, so I must've goofed something up the first time around. Also, with regexr I did in fact find that the regex works fine in v1 of the site, but not the new v2, so they must've switched to javascript regex in v2 (and this is the first time I've used v2). Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5):

You have to take care about the language. Each Language has a different implementation how a named group is defined:

JavaScript does not support it at all.

In PHP Your example would be `(?P<VersionNumber>.*?)`

In C# you should be able to use either `(?<VersionNumber>.*?)` or `(?'VersionNumber'.*?)`

you can look up some more examples here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html